# Making a graph in R from csv

Tags: r, csv

I have two csv files containing

```
First file(iteration.csv)
TIME NUMBER
2    1
5    10
12   100
15   1000
20   10000
Second file(recursion.csv)
TIME NUMBER
4    1
8    10
14   100
18   1000
29   10000
```

CSV files values changes according to another program...therefore i cannot draw graph manually

```
i want to plot a bar graph 
x axis-NUMBER
y axis-Comparison of iteration and recursion(TIME)
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do plot using plot function, you can do this in this way:

```
## First File
firstfile <- data.frame(TIME = c(2,5,12,15,20), NUMBER = c(1,1e1,1e2,1e3,1e4))

## Second File
secondfile <- data.frame(TIME = c(4,8,14,18,29),NUMBER = c(1,1e1,1e2,1e3,1e4))

test <- rbind(firstfile$TIME,secondfile$TIME)

dimnames(test)[[2]] <- firstfile$NUMBER

barplot(test,beside=T,col=rep(c('red','blue'),ncol(test)),main='Comparison')

legend(x = 'topleft',legend = c('Iteration','Recursion'),fill=c('red','blue'))
```

[image: GRAPH]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're looking for a grouped bar plot, which you can create with the following code:

```
  #Create two datasets
  secondfile <- data.frame(TIME = c(4,8,14,18,29),NUMBER = c(1,1e1,1e2,1e3,1e4))
  firstfile <- data.frame(TIME = c(2,5,12,15,20), NUMBER = c(1,1e1,1e2,1e3,1e4))
  #Add variable identifying group
  firstfile$GROUP<-"Iteration"
  secondfile$GROUP <-"Recursion"
  #Row bind the data.frames
  data<-rbind(firstfile,secondfile)
  #Now graph
  library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(data, aes(as.factor(NUMBER), TIME, fill = GROUP)) + 
     geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
     xlab("NUMBER")+ylab("Iteration vs Recursion")
```

Which produces the following plot:
[image]

If you're interested in the first difference between the two you can do the following:

```
     #Take difference
     TIME_diff<-secondfile$TIME-firstfile$TIME
     #Remove previous TIME variable then add first difference
     firstfile$TIME<-NULL
     firstfile$TIME<-TIME_diff
     #Now row bind to previous dataset
     data<-rbind(data, first file)
     #And graph
     ggplot(data2, aes(as.factor(NUMBER), TIME, fill = GROUP)) + 
     geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
     xlab("NUMBER")+ylab("Iteration vs Recursion")
```

And this is what it looks likes:
    [image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
#firstfile <- read.csv("iteration.csv")
firstfile <- data.frame(TIME = c(2,5,12,15,20), NUMBER = c(1,1e1,1e2,1e3,1e4))
#   TIME NUMBER
# 1    2      1
# 2    5     10
# 3   12    100
# 4   15   1000
# 5   20  10000

#secondfile <- read.csv("recursion.csv")
secondfile <- data.frame(TIME = c(4,8,14,18,29),NUMBER = c(1,1e1,1e2,1e3,1e4))

barplot(firstfile[["TIME"]]/secondfile[["TIME"]],
        names.arg = firstfile[["NUMBER"]])
```

[image: Barplot]